# How to update DB from Datagridview c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

How to update DB from Datagridview c# ?  My project is work for load data table in DB.but can't update into DB 
It's load data button

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString;

        connectionString = "Server=localhost;User Id=root; Password=1234; Database=db2; Pooling=false;CharSet=tis620;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from data Where Id = '" + comp.Text.Trim() + "'", connection);

        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        Table1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

and update button

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        cmdbl = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);

        sda.Update(dt);
        MessageBox.Show("Save data complete");

}
```

I follow this clip [Insert,Delete and Update data in database from datagridview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sB0A6FIhUM)
and i can't do it 
Sorry for my english I speak not good enough   and thank you for answer.

Comment: try  dt.AcceptChanges() after update

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have UpdateCommand configured.
try dt.AcceptChanges() after update

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cmdbl = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);

    sda.Update(dt);
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    MessageBox.Show("Save data complete");

  }
```

Otherwise follow the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx)

As a minimum requirement, you must set the SelectCommand property in order for automatic command generation to work. The table schema retrieved by the SelectCommand property determines the syntax of the automatically generated INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
The DbCommandBuilder must execute the SelectCommand in order to return the metadata necessary to construct the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE SQL commands. As a result, an extra trip to the data source is necessary, and this can hinder performance. To achieve optimal performance, specify your commands explicitly rather than using the DbCommandBuilder.
**The SelectCommand must also return at least one primary key or unique column.** If none are present, an InvalidOperation exception is generated, and the commands are not generated.

Comment: aw  sorry sir i have error "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records." from sda.update(dt);